# Getting confused with SQL foreign key and many to many

Tags: sql, database-design, foreign-keys

Suppose you have students and teachers. A student has only one teacher but teachers have many students.

What is the best way to design it with a relational table ?

```
Student      Teacher
-------      -------
pk           pk
name         name
teacher
```

or

```
Student      Teacher        Relation
-------      -------        --------
pk           pk             pk
name         name           student
                            teacher
```

To me it's more comfortable to use the second solution because web can add fields like

> date_joined

or some stuff.

What do you advice ?

Thanks

## My choice

Thanks to your advices i've decided to use a dedicated table to be more flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the relationship, in and of itself, has attributes (that is, they're not attributes of the teacher or the pupil) then yes, that would be a good reason to model it as a separate table.<sup>1</sup>

On the other hand, if you're only adding these attributes because you now can, then I would favour the first form.

<sup>1</sup> You may still want some form of enforcement to ensure that the "A student has only one teacher" constraint is still met, but the details of how to do that precisely may vary between database systems, and on whether the `relation` table is just modeling current relationships, or also contains historic relationships.

Answer (score 0):

If the student only has one teacher, and you know that for sure, then I would recommend the first alternative.

Even in the first solution you can have fields like date_joined

```
Student      Teacher
-------      -------
pk           pk
name         name
teacher
date_joined
```

However, quite often a student takes many courses, or has many teachers. If you go with this solution then a student can only have one teacher at the time. So you need to be sure that this is really the case.

If you go with the second solution, and you only want one teacher per student, you can add a unique index for the student. This blocks so one student only can appear once in the relational table.